# Adobe Acrobat Reader Tabs Saving And Autoloading DOES NOT WORK WELL

Tags: javascript, windows-8, adobe, autoload, acrobat

I have a problem with the JS code here

[Adobe Acrobat Reader Tabs Saving And Autoloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689154/adobe-acrobat-reader-tabs-saving-and-autoloading)

When I run AR, and open and save and load tabs everything works.

However when I open AR and try to Load Tabs, all pdf files are nonexisting.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Now I've found a partial solution and deteceted the problem.

The problem occurs only if I donwload to DESKTOP. If I download high enough in the hierarchy of files,

namely to subdirectory of D:\

the problem doesn't appear. I Don't know why, but I'm happy with this.

Perhaps someone can explain what's going wrong with downloading to DESKTOP?